# Is there a word for the "love of one's own handwriting"?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, handwriting

I sometimes just want to write something because I like to see my beautiful handwriting. Is there a word for love of one's own handwriting?

Comment: I'd say _vanity_, but that would be too broad I'm sure.

Comment: You "love your calligraphy." But there is no single word for it.

Comment: @vickyace since it is tagged neologism, can we construct a word? I was about to suggest 'autocalligraphelia'.

Comment: I think I got my spelling wrong, 'autocalligraphilia'?

Comment: @Spagirl You need nobody's permission to make new words. But just make sure the words are sensible and easily understood by most. Also, don't use it in any formal papers.

Comment: I don't think there's even a word for loving the sound of one's own voice, and there are a lot more people like that.

Comment: Either way, they probably all *think this song is about them.*

Answer (score 2):

***vanity*** comes close.

> 1 [mass noun] Excessive pride in or admiration of one’s own appearance
>   or achievements - [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vanity)

Example:

> The handsome actor's vanity was well-known.

Also try [narcissism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/narcissism).

Answer (score 1):

***Calligraphic Narcissism?***

That seems like a good way to describe the love looking at of one's own handwriting, with an implication that it's an unhealthy obsession.

I'm not sure if I've come across the word "calligraphic" before but it seems legitimate.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/calligraphy

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narcissism

Answer (score 0):

Logophilia from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logophilia) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-phil-):

> n. love of words.

Comment: How is "love of words" appropriate?

Comment: Hit us with your alternate suggestion and I will give you an upvote.

Comment: "Narcissistic logophilia"?

Comment: @MaxWilliams that would be loving the words, isn't the OP more infatuated with the form of his letters than the words they make?

Comment: That's right. This is more about the love for "handwriting".